# How to load models from data faster in PyOpenGL?

Tags: python, performance, opengl, pyopengl

I've been making a 3D game in Python using Python OpenGL. I am using a lot of .obj files made from Blender mainly because there are animations and a lot of models. It seems to take a long time to load and parse these files (it took minutes) and convert them into vertices. How can I load these files faster?

From https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/70330/efficient-way-of-loading-wavefront-models-in-opengl-game I found the possible solutions of dumping the obj data into memory (files) and putting all the small files into a large file, but I don't know how to do either of those.

When I am using .gltf files as an alternative, I found the pytf module from PYPI but doesn't know how to use it.

Thanks in advance,

Noah

Comment: Taking minutes to load a bunch of model files seems awfully slow, even for a non-ideal format like .obj. How many and how large are these files? What loader are you using to do this work?

Comment: @CodeSurgeon I am using animations from blender. Since I have to make a separate .obj file for each frame there are hundreds or even thousands of them. A file is about 150KB.

Comment: My recommendation would be to scrap this approach and see if you cannot convince Blender to generate output files suitable for skeletal animation (this would need a single .obj file, a list of bones + bone weights, and then position/rotation information for each bone in an animation.

Comment: If you cannot do the above, consider pre-processing your .obj files into packed binary files (eg the [PLY binary format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLY_(file_format)) ) so you can upload the entire vertex information to a Vertex Buffer Object and the face information to a separate Index Buffer Object. Your draw call is then a single `glDrawElements`.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon It seems like blender doesn't support animations for .ply format?

Comment: Loading an individual 150KB file for every animation frame is inefficient no matter how you do it. Even so, 150MB should load in maybe ten seconds, not a few minutes.

Comment: An alternative format you can consider is glTF. I believe khronos (the OpenGL committee people) have made an exporter for blender. You can choose to use a binary format for the exported file to make it even faster if needed. If you are using the OBJloader I see often on the pygame website, that might be inefficient too. I think it loads the vertex data into a python list, whereas a contiguous numpy array would be much preferred for copying the data efficiently to the gpu.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon Thank you! I will definitely try that.

Comment: I am actually working on writing a game engine myself using cython. I can probably work on churning out a faster basic obj parser in the next couple of weeks since this is one of those questions that keeps on cropping up.

Comment: Not sure if you ran into [this obj loader](https://github.com/pywavefront/PyWavefront/blob/master/README.md) but it seems to have a decent eye for performance (interleaving data, caching to binary for faster future loading, etc).

Comment: @CodeSurgeon No, it took longer to load, especially the textures.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I hadn't personally tested it out but it had seemed promising. Another one to consider would be the assimp library, which should have a python library. For my own code at the moment, I am struggling to handle the different kinds of incomplete data that an obj file can contain (e.g. missing normals or missing texture coordinates).

Comment: Keep finding more of these loaders the more I look around! [Here](https://pypi.org/project/tinyobjloader/) is a wrapper around a c++ library by the same name that can load obj and mtl files.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon Error while installing: ```bindings.cc:1:10: fatal error: 'pybind11/pybind11.h' file not found```?

Comment: Do you have pybind11 installed? That python library is responsible for making the c++ to python binding possible in this case. You should be able to pip install pybind11 to get that one.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon Yeah sure, I should've done that.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon Another error: ```bindings.cc:10:10: fatal error: 'tiny_obj_loader.h' file not found```. This time, I can't even install this package using pip.

Comment: Now that is more interesting! When I pip installed tinyobjloader, I did not need to have already installed the c++ library, as it was installed during that process. I guess you can copy the header (.h) file manually from the github repo for tinyobjloader to fix that, but this should not be necessary to do by hand.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon When I directly download the source code as a zip file it says ```AttributeError: module 'tinyobjloader' has no attribute 'ObjReader'```. Why is this happening?

Comment: Not too sure. My best guess is that, since this is not a header-only library (unlike their c99 version of the code), some additional files or compilation may be needed. What os and python version are you on, and what was the original error message when you tried to pip install tinyobjloader (without the copied in zip file stuff)?

Comment: @CodeSurgeon    ```gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -I../ -I../pybind11/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c bindings.cc -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/bindings.o -std=c++11
    bindings.cc:10:10: fatal error: 'tiny_obj_loader.h' file not found
    #include "tiny_obj_loader.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1``` I am using MacOS and Python version 3.7.1.

Comment: Thanks for including that. While I don't get that error on my linux laptop and python 3.6, I do get a similar error to you trying to install the package on windows through msys2. In the meantime, I have been busy writing my own obj loader in cython. You can take a look at what I have [here](https://github.com/AnishN/pyorama/tree/master/pyorama/loaders). It currently runs about 3x as slow as tinyobjloader, but should be simpler to read and modify while I make it more robust and error tolerant.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon Thank you so much for your time spent on this topic! I will certainly reply if it works.